# QFileSystemModel - Name filters and readOnly

Tags: c++, qt

I've got some question with `QFileSystemModel`, I can't figure out why when I choose to hide some file by extension, the others are still showed up but with an hidden file style and I want to `setReadOnly(false)` only files to avoid the renaming of folders.

Here is an exemple:

```
QVBoxLayout *dockLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
QFileSystemModel *dockModel = new QFileSystemModel;
dockModel->setRootPath("C:/path");
dockModel->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.typ"); //It does show all other types but they are like hidden and unchangeable
dockModel->setReadOnly(false); //I want to setReadOnly(false) for file and (true) for folders.
QTreeView *view = new QTreeView;
view->setModel(dockModele);
view->setRootIndex(dockModele->index("C:/path"));
view->hideColumn(1);
view->hideColumn(2);
view->hideColumn(3);
dockLayout->addWidget(view);
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: I've figured out how to hide the "hidden styled" files by putting `dockModele->setNameFilterDisables(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a quick fix might be to derive your own item model that only allows editing for Files, not Directories:

```
class MyFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
    typedef QFileSystemModel super;
protected:
    virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex & index) const override
    {
        // Retreive initial flags from QFileSystemModel's implementation
        Qt::ItemFlags flags = super::flags(index);

        // Retain all flags except for the Editable flag
        flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;

        // Enable editing for all file types except directories
        if(!isDir(index))
            flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;

        return flags;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tested it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So you can still edit directories? Sorry I only compiled, didn't step through it. Does the if(type(index) != "Directory") line work as it is supposed to?

Comment: Yes, I can still. And the `if(type(index) != "Directory")` is incorrect. I changed it by `if(!(this->isDir(index)))` and now it works perfectly!

Comment: Just wanted to say, another way would be to change the string to "Folder". But isDir() looks way cleaner!